# Display data as per their group name inside forloop php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I havecustomer,agent and balance table.
I want to display data as per their belonging agentname.

for ex - In below customer table,i have agentId and prodname,each agent have multiple products like abc and def belongs to agent raj and xyz prod belongs to agent test ,So raj and test will display once.

Balance table have bal_amt associated with thier agent_id,so bal_amt will display on footer of each agentname.

```
Customertable
id agent_id catname 
1    1       abc
2    1       def
3    2       xyz

Agenttable
id     name
1      raj
2      test

Balancetable
id agent_id  bal_amt
1    1        25000
2    2        7000
```

**My sql query data**

```
     Array
(
    [id] => 73
    [agent_id] => 5
    [prodname] => abc
    [subprodname] => test 
    [quantity] => 2
    [rate] => 120
    [amount] => 240
    [paid_amount] => 240
    [balance] => Array
        (            
            [agent_id] => 5
            [bal_amt] => 14000

        )
    [agent] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Duryodhan nimbarte
        )
)
Array
(
    [id] => 72
    [agent_id] => 5
    [prodname] => abc
    [subprodname] => test  
    [quantity] => 5
    [rate] => 200
    [amount] => 1000
    [paid_amount] => 700
    [balance_amount] => 300
    [balance] => Array
        (            
            [agent_id] => 5
            [bal_amt] => 14000
        )   
    [agent] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Duryodhan nimbarte
        )
)
Array
(
    [id] => 71
    [agent_id] => 6
    [prodname] => abc
    [subprodname] => test 
    [quantity] => 3
    [rate] => 200
    [amount] => 600
    [paid_amount] => 200
    [balance_amount] => 400
    [is_deleted] => 0
    [balance] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 6
            [bal_amt] => 14000
        )   

    [agent] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => Narhari Hedau
        )

)
```

**Expected result**

```
 Agentname  catname subprodname quantity rate amount paid_amount
    raj
                abc     test         10     5      100    80
                def     def          25     5      300    200
                25000
    test
                xyz     cde          35     10     1800   700
                7000
```

**Below is my code**

```
<?php  
    $finalArray = [];
    foreach ($customerlist as $user) { 
        $finalArray[$user['agent']['name']][] = $user;
    }
    foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><?php echo $key; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($value as $user) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td> 
        <td><?php if(!empty($user['product']['name'])){echo $user['product']['name']; } ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

**Right now i am getting below result**

```
Agentname  catname 
raj
            abc
            def
test
            xyz
```

Comment: why r u not joining table with SQL.?

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question? Is it how to get the balance? I'd suggest showing your database request code.

Comment: no i am getting balance mount by joining tables but i dont know how to display balance amount in footer of each agent name..i am updating database request code..

Comment: i have updated my database request code as well as table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php
$customerlist = [ ['id' => 1, 'agent_id' => 1, 'prodname' => 'abc', "subprodname" => "test", "quantity" => 2, "rate" => 120, "amount" => 240, 
    "paid_amount" => 240, 'balance' => [ 'agent_id' => 1, 'bal_amt'=> 25000], 'agent' => ['name' => "raj"] ],
    ['id' => 2, 'agent_id' => 1, 'prodname' => 'def', "subprodname" => "test", "quantity" => 5, "rate" => 200, "amount" => 1000, 
    "paid_amount" => 700, 'balance' => [ 'agent_id' => 1, 'bal_amt'=> 25000], 'agent' => ['name' => "raj"] ],
    ['id' => 3, 'agent_id' => 2, 'prodname' => 'xyz', "subprodname" => "test", "quantity" => 3, "rate" => 200, "amount" => 600, 
    "paid_amount" => 200, 'balance' => [ 'agent_id' => 2, 'bal_amt'=> 7000], 'agent' => ['name' => "test"] ]
 ];

    $finalArray = [];
     foreach ($customerlist as $user) { 
        $finalArray[$user['agent']['name']]['x']['prodname'] = $user['balance']['bal_amt'];
        $finalArray[$user['agent']['name']]['x']['agent'] = $user['agent']['name'];
    }
    foreach ($customerlist as $user) { 
        $finalArray[$user['agent']['name']][] = $user;
    }
    foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value) {
?>
<table border= "1px solid black">
<?php 

 foreach ( $value as $user) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php if(!is_array($user['agent'])){ echo $user['agent'];} ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $user['prodname']; /*if(!empty($user['product']['name'])){ }*/ ?></td>
        <td><?php if(!empty($user['subprodname'])){ echo $user['subprodname'];}  ?></td>
        <td><?php if(!empty($user['quantity'])){ echo $user['quantity']; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if(!empty($user['rate'])){  echo $user['rate']; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if(!empty($user['amount'])){  echo $user['amount']; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if(!empty($user['paid_amount'])){  echo $user['paid_amount']; } ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } } ?>
</table>
```

Output:

```
Agentname  catname subprodname quantity rate amount paid_amount
raj        25000  
            abc     test         10     5      100    80
            def     def          25     5      300    200

test        7000 
            xyz     cde          35     10     1800   700
```

Comment: ...yes its working correctly when i tried your code as it is...but i have multiple columns to display not only prodname  
$finalArray[$user['agent']['name']][] = $user['prodname'];
So i tried like below
$finalArray[$user['agent']['name']][] = $user; and tried to print inside foreach but its not working..can u explain why ??

Comment: Please add all other column in SQL. That will help to me

Comment: i have updated my sql data as well as expected result

Comment: Vicky try now. and let me know if it is working fine.

Comment: yes its okay and i am accepting your answer now but i have one more query...it is not possible to display agent name and bal_amt in same row ??..bcz it will take 2 rows one for agent name and one to display balance amount                                                    <tr>
        <td colspan="7"><?php echo $key; ?></td>
 <td colspan="7"><?php echo $bal_amount; ?></td>
    </tr>..like wise

Comment: `raj   2500` do you want like this?

Comment: yes exactly..i want to display balance amount in same row with agent name